# PDI Kettle Parameter in RegEx

Tags: pentaho, kettle

I'm new in pentaho's world and I wanted to use a parameter to use my regex.

It's working when I try my regex with the field `Test regEx` of a step Regex Evaluation.
But it's not working when I'm trying to run the kettle.

My RegEx is `.*(?i)${TOOL_NAME}.*`

I'm getting this from logs :
`ERROR (version 5.0.6, build 1 from 2014-04-26_17-32-54 by buildguy) : Step [test regex.0] failed to initialize!`

I'm already using parameters for other fields and it's working fine.

Anthony

Comment: Just to get an idea of the complexity of the expression, could you include it into your question? Thanks!

Comment: I forgot thanks for the reminder, it's very simple as you can see ...

Comment: Is `PARAM` a Kettle system variable?

Comment: I'm using `TOOL_NAME` in fact, it was just to make it more understandable

Comment: I guess you have activated the flag `use variable substitution`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The use of system variables in the regex component requires the setting `use variable substitution` to be activated. Otherwise the string `${PARAM}` will be interpreted literally, most likely resulting in an invalid regular expression which can not be compiled.